# Skills assessment for Australian visa: Medium stream temporary visitor visa subclass 482

Tags: visa, australia, indian-citizens

I am a PhD student and have been offered to join as a postdoctoral fellow (University Lecturer - 242111) at Australian National University. While applying for the medium stream temporary visitor visa subclass 482, I came accross the following question under the section 'Skills assessment'.

Type of skills assessment: (with five options)

```
457/TSS Skills assessment: TRA

Other trades recognition Australian skills assessment

Meat industry training advisory council assessment

Skills assessment for migration -General Occupations- VETASSESS

Other
```

The question is mandatory and there are follow up questions (Name, Date, Identification Number) once I select a particular option.

Please let me know if more information is required from my side.

Comment: Did you figure it out or are you still wondering how to answer it?

Comment: I am still wondering how to answer it :(

Comment: @gerrit can you please help?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I have no clue what the answer is!